# AWS Elemental MediaConvert not working with MP3 input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I am trying to use AWS Elemental MediaConvert for AOD (Audio on-demand) HLS streaming. Below is my Job description

```
{
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "CustomName": "HLS",
        "Name": "Apple HLS",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "ContainerSettings": {
              "Container": "M3U8",
              "M3u8Settings": {
                "AudioFramesPerPes": 4,
                "PcrControl": "PCR_EVERY_PES_PACKET",
                "PmtPid": 480,
                "PrivateMetadataPid": 503,
                "ProgramNumber": 1,
                "PatInterval": 0,
                "PmtInterval": 0,
                "Scte35Source": "NONE",
                "NielsenId3": "NONE",
                "TimedMetadata": "NONE",
                "VideoPid": 481,
                "AudioPids": [
                  482,
                  483,
                  484,
                  485,
                  486,
                  487,
                  488,
                  489,
                  490,
                  491,
                  492
                ]
              }
            },
            "AudioDescriptions": [
              {
                "AudioTypeControl": "FOLLOW_INPUT",
                "AudioSourceName": "Audio Selector 1",
                "CodecSettings": {
                  "Codec": "AAC",
                  "AacSettings": {
                    "AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix": "NORMAL",
                    "Bitrate": 96000,
                    "RateControlMode": "CBR",
                    "CodecProfile": "LC",
                    "CodingMode": "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                    "RawFormat": "NONE",
                    "SampleRate": 48000,
                    "Specification": "MPEG4"
                  }
                },
                "LanguageCodeControl": "FOLLOW_INPUT"
              }
            ],
            "OutputSettings": {
              "HlsSettings": {
                "AudioGroupId": "program_audio",
                "AudioTrackType": "AUDIO_ONLY_VARIANT_STREAM",
                "IFrameOnlyManifest": "EXCLUDE"
              }
            },
            "NameModifier": "string"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "HLS_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "HlsGroupSettings": {
            "ManifestDurationFormat": "INTEGER",
            "SegmentLength": 10,
            "TimedMetadataId3Period": 10,
            "CaptionLanguageSetting": "OMIT",
            "Destination": "s3://<MEDIABUCKET>/HLS/",
            "TimedMetadataId3Frame": "PRIV",
            "CodecSpecification": "RFC_4281",
            "OutputSelection": "MANIFESTS_AND_SEGMENTS",
            "ProgramDateTimePeriod": 600,
            "MinSegmentLength": 0,
            "DirectoryStructure": "SINGLE_DIRECTORY",
            "ProgramDateTime": "EXCLUDE",
            "SegmentControl": "SEGMENTED_FILES",
            "ManifestCompression": "NONE",
            "ClientCache": "ENABLED",
            "StreamInfResolution": "INCLUDE"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "AdAvailOffset": 0,
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "EMBEDDED",
        "FileInput": "s3://kg-media-test/inputs/test_audio.mp4"
      }
    ]
}
```

But whenever I am giving an MP3 file as input it's throwing below error -

```
Exception: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateJob operation: /inputs/0/fileInput: 
Should match the pattern: /^(http|https|s3)://([^/]+/)+([^/\.]+|(([^/]*)\.([mM]2[vV]|[mM][pP][eE][gG]|[aA][vV][iI]|[mM][pP]4|[fF][lL][vV]|[mM][pP][tT]|[mM][pP][gG]|[mM]4[vV]|[tT][rR][pP]|[fF]4[vV]|[mM]2[tT][sS]|[tT][sS]|264|[hH]264|[mM][kK][vV]|[mM][oO][vV]|[mM][tT][sS]|[mM]2[tT]|[wW][mM][vV]|[aA][sS][fF]|[vV][oO][bB]|3[gG][pP]|3[gG][pP][pP]|[mM][xX][fF]|[dD][iI][vV][xX]|[xX][vV][iI][dD]|[rR][aA][wW]|[dD][vV]|[gG][xX][fF]|[mM]1[vV]|3[gG]2|[vV][mM][fF]|[mM]3[uU]8|[wW][eE][bB][mM]|[lL][cC][hH]|[gG][xX][fF]_[mM][pP][eE][gG]2|[mM][xX][fF]_[mM][pP][eE][gG]2|[mM][xX][fF][hH][dD]|[wW][aA][vV]|[yY]4[mM]|[xX][mM][lL])))$/
```

It looks like there is a Regex validation on the input file name and MP3 files are not allowed. But according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/reference-codecs-containers-input.html) documentation, MP3 is a valid input file.

If I convert that MP3 file to an MP4 file and then try then the job is producing HLS without any error.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is of course very late but your json has this.

```
"Destination": "s3://<MEDIABUCKET>/HLS/",
```

It was probably your issue.